# Панель ubuntu 16.04 (unity) как запущенные программы сделать заметнее?

Tags: ubuntu

Сейчас у запущенных две стрелочки сверху и снизу (см.фото). Как сделать заметнее? Например окрасить фон и т.д.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть целое сообщество ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com

Comment: мне казалось пользователи убунту презирают мак)

Comment: Поставить другой shell)